# smartphone proximity detection

Tags: android, iphone, ios, bluetooth, nfc

I want to implement proximity detection for a smartphone (iPhone or Android) for when it comes within "close range" of a computer. In other words I want a program running on a computer to know when a smartphone is nearby, and also to be able to uniquely identify that phone.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with bluetooth or some sort of server element

Note that the bluetooth would have to be preconfigured to auto connect to the computer. This route would require the jailbreak land so that you could attach your own code to run once a bluetooth connection was established.

The other route, which could work in the app store, would be to have the phone check its location ever so often and send this information to your server. The server would then do some sort of check on the location of the computer and compare the two. You could then have a push notification sent to an iphone or just send a packet to an android app